# How should I connect a Meross 4-way switch?

Tags: wiring, multiway-switch

I have a Meross 3 way HomeKit switch with these instructions that I have successfully installed on a normal 3 way circuit:

[image]

Now the issue - I also have a 4 way circuit:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The 4 way clear is connected to the two traveller switches (each connected to single 3 wire) and also to the lights which have power supplied to them. The part I don’t get is why there is a 3 wire from the lights.

Any thoughts on how to connect this?

Comment: Are you wedded to the Meross switches?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a 3-wire from the lights going to the 4-way. What you have is:

- First 3-way (can't tell which is which from the pictures, but doesn't matter):

  - Black = incoming hot (white from that cable goes to the light)
  - White and Red = travellers (black from that cable doesn't touch this switch but goes to the light)
- 4-way

  - Blacks = switched hot *passing through* but not connected to the switch
  - White and Red = travellers
- Second 3-way

  - Black = switched hot to light (but gets there by going to (but not touching) the 4-way and then to the first 3-way (but not touching) and then to the light)
  - White and Red = travellers

This keeps everything balanced. The 3-way/4-way cables are travellers (one dead, one live) + switched dead. The light gets switched hot and neutral.

Be careful replacing the 4-way switch - the screw configuration may be different. But the key is to look at how the wires are paired - you have two sets of red + white, which are each a set of travellers. The instructions on a new switch should tell you how each pair wires up - typically either a pair on the left and a pair on the right or a pair on the top and a pair on the bottom.